# Ignite and RDMS integration in client mode

Tags: ignite

I am using https://apacheignite-mix.readme.io/v1.7/docs/automatic-persistence to load data from database into Ignite cache.

I run my code with Ignite client mode, and want to load the data into Ignite Cluster.

It looks that I have to put my user code jar and dependent jars into $IGNITE_HOME/libs to make my code work?

I would ask:

1. Did I do the right thing to  put these jars to $IGNITE_HOME/libs to make my code work?
2. If I have to put my jars into $IGNITE_HOME/libs, it looks that if I have more tables need to be loaded after I have loaded some tables into the cache, should I have to shutdown the cluster and restart for the server to load these new classes? If so, then the data in the cache will be lost since they reside in memory,and have to reload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to load the data, through `IgniteDataStreamer` and through `CacheStore` implementation. See this page for details: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/data-loading

In case of `IgniteDataStreamer` you will load the data from DB on the client and stream it into the cluster. In this case you don't need to add any classes to server classpath.

In case of `CacheStore` you will load data from DB on server side. In this case you need to explicitly deploy (add to `libs` folder) the implementation of the `CacheStore` and anything it depends on. If you're using [Automatic Persistence](https://apacheignite-mix.readme.io/docs/automatic-persistence), the implementation is already there and nothing to deploy as well.

You're never required to have model classes on server classpath and you can dynamically change the schema without cluster restart. See this page for more information: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/binary-marshaller

Comment: Thanks @Valentin. I am using the https://apacheignite-mix.readme.io/docs/automatic-persistence, what I observed is , if I use the peer class loading, then i have to put my user code jar in one of the cluster's nodes(only one of the three cluster nodes). If I don't put the user code jar in any of the  the nodes, then ClassNotFoundException is thrown, so I looks to me that the user code should have to be placed in one of the server nodes. But this observation violates the zero deployment

Comment: Continue the above comment: Zero Deployment( With peer-class-loading enabled, you don't have to manually deploy your Java or Scala code on each node in the grid and re-deploy it each time it changes. Reference: https://apacheignite.readme.io/v1.8/docs/zero-deployment#peer-class-loading) Not sure my observation is correct!

Comment: Zero deployment is actually designed for Compute Grid, it allows to dynamically load jobs and tasks. Anything that is part of configuration (like `CacheStore` implementation), must be on the server classpath prior to start.